# How to add a custom header in AWS SNS API trigger?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I want to trigger an HTTP API using AWS SNS API trigger. The APIs I want to trigger will perform authentication using auth token which comes in the request header. How can we get the auth token which is provided by another auth rest service and add that token in the request header?
Is there any support available in AWS to add custom logic for populating the custom header before invoking the HTTP API?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any support available in AWS to add custom logic for
>   populating the custom header before invoking the HTTP API?

You should be able to achieve By using an intermediate Lambda function to do this custom auth rest service and make a call to the API.

SNS -> custom Lambda function -> API